# React - Viewport being ignored

Tags: html, reactjs, scale, viewport

In my index file I have the following:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

I am using React to load the page, but the main index file is an HTML file. (.pug)

This is inserted correctly into the DOM. However, the viewport is ignored - my page is showing the desktop version.

If I edit the DOM in the Chrome dev tools, eg. change 1 to 1.0 or any other part of the meta tag, it causes the page to re-calculate the viewport correctly, and will then display correctly straight away. Any ideas?

You might need to click the image to see the GIF animation.

[image: Animated example of issue]

Answer (score 4):

Try using `meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0')` in your index.pug file.

---

Based on your code, try using `meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0')`

Comment: I already have that: https://puu.sh/ArsUv/7fbd5d58b9.png . You can see the viewport is being loaded - it's in the DOM <head>

Comment: @fl0shizzle You aren't using double quotes / single quotes correctly. Paste what I have and try again.

Comment: DOH! Stupid quotes. Was very easy to miss with my IDE syntax highlighting. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try using this. It works for me.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1.00" maximum-scale="1.0" />`

Comment: Damn bro thanks! It worked out for me too!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try [triggering the viewport recalculation](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) manually on page load with, for example:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body)
```

<sub>*Please, note that this is not the best solution. It should just be used while (or only if) the root cause issue is not found.*</sub>